# Initialize UIImageView with a file name from the device library

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, alassetslibrary

I have a picture named IMG_0094.JPG, taken by the device's camera.

I would like initialize my `UIImageView` with it but my code doesn't work.

Following code is in `viewDidLoad`.

```
currentImageName            = [contact objectForKey:@"image"];
NSURL* aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:currentImageName];

NSLog(@"%@", aURL);

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library assetForURL:aURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
 {
     UIImage  *copyOfOriginalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage] scale:0.5 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

     UIImageView *photo = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:TAG_PHOTO];
     photo.image = copyOfOriginalImage;
     photo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
 }
        failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
 {
     // error handling
     NSLog(@"failure---");
 }];
```

My NSLOG return 2015-02-26 10:39:54.899 Fiche Contacts[1600:60b] IMG_0094.JPG

Comment: The url doesnt seem to be a URL but just the name of the image the URL would look something like ` assets-library://asset/IMG_0094.JPG?id=1ECB69B9-DC7A-45A7-B135-F43317D3412C&ext=JPG`

Comment: yes i know this, but there is anyway to get the image?

Comment: the solution : http://www.to-string.com/2014/04/30/how-to-extract-string-reference-to-an-image-in-ios-and-then-load-the-image-later/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, use the url which is generate when the picture is saved : http://www.to-string.com/2014/04/30/how-to-extract-string-reference-to-an-image-in-ios-and-then-load-the-image-later/